# How to send/share multiple (big)remote files on Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have an app that shows me pictures and videos that are stored somewhere. I can access these pictures and videos via HTTP by token and URL.

How can I share this data via my Android app with other applications, e.g. via Whats App, email etc.?

The code I currently have only works with URI, files that are already on the device. But I can't always download all the pictures and videos temporarily to share them. That would take too long. Is there a way to pass the input stream to other applications?

```
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
            shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileURIs);
            shareIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, null));
```

Comment: You can not do such thing with `Intent`. file has to present in local storage to send so you need to download it first .

Comment: Oh, too bad, that's probably the reason I can't find anything about it.

Comment: You should just send the urls to those other apps. As if you can use an url to display a file those other apps can too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass the input stream to other applications by using the `Intent.EXTRA_STREAM and the setType()` method.

First, you need to create an array of URI objects which will contain all the image or video files you want to share. For example:

```
ArrayList<Uri> fileURIs = new ArrayList<Uri>();

// Add all the URIs to the array
for (String url : urls) {
    fileURIs.add(Uri.parse(url));
}
```

Then, create an Intent object with the ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE action, set the type to "image/*" or "video/*", and include the array of URIs as an extra. For example:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileURIs);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, null));
```

Finally, call start.
Hope this helps and that i answered your question!

Comment: `Yes, you can pass the input stream to other applications by using the Intent.EXTRA_STREAM ` No. You cannot pass an InputStream. And what your code does is passing a list of uries. Not streams.

Comment: oh, then sorry ;(